# How to run git commands through MATLAB script?

Tags: git, matlab

I am trying to run git command through matlab script and get the terminal output.
I have had success when running

```
[status,cmdoutput] =  system('TERM=ansi git diff-tree -r --name-only asdasd asdasdas');
```

However if I use git diff instead of git diff-tree, I get empty result back. I have tried to run the same command on  terminal which runs fine.

OS : Ubuntu 18.04
MATLAB R2020b

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What OS? Windows?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What program do you have configured to do `diff`?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. I have git installed if that is what you are asking. I cloned a repo from GitHub and am changing my directory to that repo before running the git command. As I have said 'git diff-tree' command returns me the output but git diff returns empty characters. I am guessing this has to do with having to press Return key to execute the command but havent really found a way around. More over it is interesting diff-tree works fine while diff does not.

Comment: You can configure git to use an external program to do the diffs. If you didn’t know this, you likely didn’t. You could try `got diff —raw`, to see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be related to the pager. I've been using the following code without problem on Ubuntu 20.04

```
[~, cmdoutput] = system('git --no-pager diff --no-color');
```

Comment: @Sohil How do you store the result of the command to a variable in MATLAB ? Eg I have to run this command [~, out.git_hash] = system('!git config --global user.name'); but don't know where the result is stored to do a disp(result)..

Comment: In my case, I am running a git diff to get list of files changed between two commits. I do that by doing this : [status,cmdoutput] =  system('TERM=ansi git diff -r --name-only <SHA before> <SHA after>').  I then clean the cmdoutput and that works for me. I believe in your case you would just want to check if the status == 0 as you just want to make sure that your git command executed successfully.