# Store git command result into a variable using MATLAB script

Tags: git, matlab

I'm trying to get the result after executing the git command function  `!git config --global user.name` which outputs my username in the command prompt of my MATLAB.

Now if I assign the same to a variable to use it in another instance I'm getting the below error as shown below.

```
userName = !git config --global user.name

Error : Parse error at !git config --global user.name : Usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax

disp(userName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need something like

```
[~, out.git_hash] = system('git rev-parse --verify HEAD');
[~, out.git_status] = system('git --no-pager diff --no-color');
```

etc.

On Windows, depending on different options during setup, you may need to supply the full path to the git binary, e.g.

```
[~, out.git_hash] = system('"C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git"  rev-parse --verify HEAD'); 
[~, out.git_status] = system('"C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git" --no-pager diff --no-color');
```

[Just be cautious with pager-related parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74355335/how-to-run-git-commands-through-matlab-script)

Comment: Thanks but where to find the data that returns system('git rev-parse --verify HEAD'); ? Does it store in ~ ?

Comment: @forgottofly Oh you will get a variable called 'out' of 'struct' type, with several fields. There should be the thing you are looking for. You can also replace the '~' with other variable names, to checkout [return status](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html). I find them less helpful once the code is stable, so ignored them in the example.

Comment: @forgottofly also you don't have to use the 'sturct' type for return, you can just name your variable however you like it. The actual data should be a char array. I just copied working code where a struct type fits better.